# Redirection operator in C not working

Tags: c, linux

I'm just doing this C program, which acts like a terminal and I've implemented the "dir" command, but I also want to implement the redirection ">" operator, so I can redirect everything to a file. I made a C program that waits for my input, and I want that input to be sent to the .txt file.

This is the output.c, which waits for an user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 500

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

char text[SIZE];

scanf("%s", text);

return 0;

}
```

And this is the code that should redirect my input to my file.
UPDATE:

```
int rv;
pid_t pid;
int commpipe[2];

if(argc > 2){

    char filename[] = "output.txt";
    int old_prn_han, new_prn_han;

    old_prn_han = dup(fileno(stdout));
    strcpy(filename, argv[2]);

    if((new_prn_han = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create/open file '%s'\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    dup2(new_prn_han, fileno(stdout));

    if((pid=fork()) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking new process!\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    if(pid){
        //Parent process
        close(commpipe[0]);
        setvbuf(stdout,(char*)NULL,_IONBF,0);
        sleep(2);
        wait(&rv);
        fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with a %d value\n", rv);
    }else{
    //Child process
        dup2(commpipe[0],0);
        close(commpipe[1]);

        if(execl("output", "output", NULL) == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error executing new process!\n");
            exit(3);
        }
    } 


    close(fileno(stdout));
    dup2(old_prn_han, fileno(stdout));

}
```

The problem is, that it seems my output program, which awaits user input does not execute. Can you guys help me out ?

UPDATE
I've updated my code. Now the new process is executing but when i type something in like 'name' at stdin, my file contains some weird symbols and they do not appear until I exit my main program. Why is that ?

Comment: What happens instead? You're not waiting for `output` to exit so your program would just continue.

Comment: When I type `dir > output.txt`. Please ignore that dir, I just coded this inside an if argv[0] is dir, the output program does not execute and the main program, the terminal just continues. But when I exit from my main program, a string like "#[A" appears in my created txt file.

Comment: The terminal would just continue even if it worked, because you don't wait for the process to finish (it's like running `./output &` in a real shell). You can use `wait` (`man 2 wait`) if you want your shell to wait for `output` to finish. It probably does execute correctly, but you won't be able to tell because your shell just continues. (You can use `strace` to see if this is the case)

Comment: Hey, I've edited my post, can you please have a look at it ?

Comment: Where do you put the code? Your main issues a scanf and then exits without calling anything to process text. Thus, when you finish entering the text you are done.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't quite understood what you were trying to say. Can you reexplain please ?

Comment: Your main has the return immediately after the scanf() in the initial block of code. You do not show where the additional code would go (though I could assume that it is supposed to be immediately after the scanf() but you should make that clear. Also where do you actually either use "text" as the output buffer or copy it to the output buffer?

Comment: regarding this line: `strcpy(filename, argv[2]);`  If the user entered, at the command line a file name of (for instance) `outputs.txt` then the call to `strcpy()` will overflow the `filename[]` array, which results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: char *filename = "output.txt";  ... filename = argv[1];

Comment: this line: `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create/open file '%s'\n", filename);` leaves the user with no idea as to why the open failed.  suggest: `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create/open file '%s' due to %s\n", filename, stderror(errno) );`  Then the reason that the system thinks it failed to open the file will also be output.

Comment: this line: ` sleep(2);` has not useful action (in the current context) so should be eliminated.

Comment: regarding this line: `fprintf(stderr, "Child exited with a %d value\n", rv);`  the macros `WIFEXITED( rv)` and/or `WEXITSTATUS(rv)` and/or `WIFSIGNALED(rv)` need to be used to get the exit status of the child.  For this specific scenario, suggest replacing the `rv` parameter in the `fprintf()` statement with `WEXITSTATUS(rv)`.

Comment: why is there `commpipe[2]` and any fiddling with it when there is no communication between the parent and the child?

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%s", text);`  the user can easily overrun the input buffer `text`, even though `text` is 500 bytes.   Strongly suggest using: `scanf("%499s", text);` because 1) avoids the undefined behaviour of overrunning the input buffer. 2) allows room for the NUL byte that `scanf()` will always append when using a '%s' format specifier.